# how to extract one filed from curl response

Tags: json, bash, curl

I wanna extract one file from my curl response and jq doesn't work for me.

here is my response:

```
response = {"response":[{"id":"0-0","enabled":true}]}
```

I wanna extract the response decision (for the above case the decision is true as the value of "enabled" is true). any suggestions? thanks.

I tried

```
echo $response | grep -o '"enabled":"[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$'

jq -r .enabled <<< $respons
```

for jq:  command not found

Comment: There is no `"` after `"enabled":`, yet you `grep` for one.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

response="{\"response\":[{\"id\":\"0-0\",\"enabled\":true}]}"

echo "$response" | jq '.response[0].enabled'
```

Will return true.

Read up on jq here: http://www.compciv.org/recipes/cli/jq-for-parsing-json/

---

How I built the `jq` string:

```
$ echo "$response" | jq '.'
{
"response": [
    {
    "id": "0-0",
    "enabled": true
    }
]
}

$ echo "$response" | jq '.response'
[
{
    "id": "0-0",
    "enabled": true
}
]

$ echo "$response" | jq '.response[0]'
{
"id": "0-0",
"enabled": true
}

$ echo "$response" | jq '.response[0].enabled'
true
```